# Monitor downloading apps/files on Android

Tags: android, monitoring

I am trying to write a code for Android so it would be like a listener/monitor that checks any app going to be downloaded and maybe logs it (log the source URL)

Can anyone help me with this? Any tutorial or sample code would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Fortunately, this is not supported, for obvious security and privacy reasons. While there are some script-kiddie hacks to get at this information, that has been closed off in Jelly Bean (Android 4.1).